# Why does std::uniform_int_distribution not give the same answer across different systems?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

Code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    mt19937 generator(0);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(0, 100);

    for(auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
         cout << distr(generator) << "\n";
    }
}
```

This code produces different numbers on Mac and Windows, but replacing `uniform_int_distribution` with `uniform_real_distribution` fixes that issue, and sequence generated is the same on both platforms.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The algorithm for distributions is not specified, different implementations may produce different results.

(The only thing the standard does specify are the raw random bit engines; *those* produce predictable results.)